# How can I terminate a do-while loop after execution?

Tags: java

I’m not sure what statement should be replaced with `(choice!=o);` in this code:

1. `choice` is a char for the switch case Y,y,N,n.
2. Terminate after `checkEmployment()` and `evaluate()` is finished running, or if `default` is invoked

```java
    do {
          System.out.println("Are you employed?");
          System.out.println("[Y] I am employed.");
          System.out.println("[N] I am unemployed.");
          choice = inputInfo.next().charAt(0);
               
          switch(choice) {
               case 'Y': checkEmployment();
               break;
               case 'y': checkEmployment();
               break;
               case 'N': evaluate();
               break;
               case 'n': evaluate();
               break;
               default: System.out.println("Invalid input. Terminating Program");
               break;
           }//This is the conditional for the employment status.
        } while(choice!='o'); //This is the do-while statement for the employment status.
```

I’m learning and any help would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking or what you're trying to do. Clarify your question please.

Comment: Why do you want ot replace the statement? Only thing missing seems to be a `System.out.println("[o] to terminate program.");`. Also, the statement is `while (choice != 'o')`, not `while (choice != 0)`.

Comment: What is `choices`?; *what statement should be replaced with (choice!=0);* - I think you mean the other way around: with what this should be replaced. Yet, why do you want to replace this?; Terminate the loop after an execution of **what**? it is impossible to answer this question if you will not clarify the points I mention.

Comment: 1) “choice” is a char for the switch case Y,y,N,n. 2) Terminate after checkEmployment and evaluate is finished running, or if default is invoked.

Comment: @GabeMempin please [edit] the post and add this information. In the comments, the information may get lost.

Answer (score 1):

You can tidy the switch statement up a bit by getting rid of two of the breaks. Then I would add a boolean to keep track of valid input. Use that as your while condition.

```
boolean validInput = false;

do {
  System.out.println("Are you employed?");
  System.out.println("[Y] I am employed.");
  System.out.println("[N] I am unemployed.");
  choice = inputInfo.next().charAt(0);

  switch(choice) {
    case 'Y':
    case 'y':
      validInput = true;
      checkEmployment();
      break;
    case 'N':
    case 'n':
      validInput = true;
      evaluate();
      break;
    default:
      System.out.println("Error - invalid input");
      break;
  }
} while (!validInput);
```

Comment: `validInput == false` shall be `!validInput`. And `toLowerCase` must be `toLowerCase()`. But this is not even defined for `char`.

Comment: You're right, I should have proof read before posting. Will fix it